# jQuery find element within table generated using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a scenario where I need to find all `<td>` containing the text "Status: Full" within a table that has been created using a javascript function.

The page `<head>` contains the script that generates the markup for the event calendar. This script looks  like this (I have removed the rest of the events for illustration purposes):

```
var today = new Date();

loaded('calendarEvents', 'start', today.getFullYear(), '6', '/9#20110716 Saturday 16 July 2011. Academic Only. Status: Full/10#20110730 Saturday 30 July 2011. Academic and General Training. Status: Available/11#20110813 Saturday 13 August 2011. ');
```

The generated HTML for a td containing my text looks like this:

```
<td class="linkbg" align="center">
<b>
<span onclick="selDate = 20110625; isDate(25,5,2011,22);return false;" title=" Saturday 25 June 2011. Academic and General Training. Status: Full" style="cursor:pointer;color:#FFFFFF">25</span>
</b>
</td>
```

It turns out that I have to locate each `<td><b><span>` in this table that contains the text "Status: Full" and set the background color of that `<td>` to be red.

I thought that doing something like this on page load would have allowed me to find these `<td>`s but this is unfortunately not the case (obviously this was within a `$(document).ready();`:

```
$('td span[title*="Status: Full"]').parent().addClass("fullclass");
```

Can anyone shed some light on how I might achieve this?

Thanks,
Tristan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:contains` only works for text inside the element, not on attributes of the element.

So you need to use the attribute based selectors. Try `$('td span[onclick*="Status: Full"]')`

Comment: OK thanks guys, that definitely would be one of the issues! Does the fact that the html is added to the DOM by javascript not prevent jQuery from finding the elements using this method>?>

Comment: No. But you must make sure *your* code runs *after* the elements have been created. In this case, `ready()` sometimes isn't enough (for example for pages built with AJAX).

Answer (score 1):

The `Status: Full` content is an attribute, not element content, so the `:contains` selector won't work. You could do an attribute match:

```
$('td span[title*="Status: Full"]').parent().addClass("fullclass");
```